# Jquery perform click on <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with an external JavaScript plugin that I can not edit and works by click on the a list of thumbnail images.

For styling purpose I have had to wrap the images in an `<a>` with:

```
if(img.parent("a").length == 0){
    img.wrap('<a />');
}
```

Is there a way I can add a click for the `<a>` I have inserted which then makes this JavaScript plugin call the actions for click on a image.

I have tried this although doesn't work and gives the error: `Too much recursion`:

```
$("#thumbs a").live("click", function(){
    $(this).find("img").click();
});
```

Comment: Can you just react to the click event on the img itself?  Is there a specific reason why you're wanting to programatically click the img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
if(!img.parent("a").length){
    img.wrap('<a />').parent('a').bind('click', function() {

        // ALL THE CODE!!!

    });
}
```

You also don't need to say `if (something.length == 0)` because it will return 0 by default...so you could say, `if (!something.length)`

Answer (score 1):

`Too much recursion` means that something is looping over and over again, possibly infinitely. The reason that's happening with your current code is because `<a>` is a parent of `<img>`, so any click event on `<img>` bubble up to the parent `<a>` (search for "event bubbling" in Google). So your code is basically saying "when someone clicks on `<a>`, trigger a click on `<img>` and then `<a>` (because of event bubbling)" -- which of course causes the code to run again.

If the JavaScript plugin already has binded events to clicks on the image, I don't see why you need to bind a click event to the parent `<a>` that simply clicks on the image. What do you need to happen that isn't already happening when the user clicks on the `<img>` -- without including your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.stopPropagation();` to the click handler of the imgs.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: But then the click event he's attaching to the <a> will never get triggered, rendering it pointless code in the first place. This is what I'm confused about -- why does he need to bind a click to the <a> that simply triggers a click on the <img>, when any clicks on the <a> are already clicks on the <img> by default (unless of course he's got some padding on the <a> element... but I'm guessing that's not the case)?

Comment: yes I do have padding on the <a> and this is the gap that is not clickable at the moment. I can't change the other javascript code because it is on another server.